# Multiprocessing in python won't releae memory

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am running a multiprocessing code. The framework of the code is something like below:

```py
def func_a(x):
    #main function here
    return result

def func_b(y):
    cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=cores)
    results = pool.map(func_a, np.arange(1000)
    return results

if __name__ == '__main__':
     final_resu = []
     for i in range(0, 200):
         final_resu.append(func_b(i))
```

The problem I found in this code has two problems: Firstly, the memory continues going up during the loop. Secondly, in the task manager (windows10), the number of python executions increased step-wise, i.e. 14 to 25, to 36, to 47... with every iteration finished in the main loop.

I believe it has something wrong with the multiprocessing, but I'm not sure how to deal with it.  It looks like the multiprocessing in func_b is not deleted when the main loop finished one loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the examples in the docs show, when you're done with a `Pool` you should shut it down explicitly, via `pool.close()` followed by `pool.join()`.That said, it would be better still if, in addition, you created your `Pool` only once - e.g., pass a `Pool` as an argument to `func_b()`. and create it - and close it down - only once, in the `__name__ == '__main__'`  block.

Comment: I just found it as well. I only added a pool.close() in func_b at the last line. So far the code running looks fine. Do I have to add a pool.join() after pool.close()? Why do we need a pool.join()?

Comment: `close()` tells the pool it can shut down all the machinery for passing out new work items. `join()` waits for all current work items to complete before tearing down the rest of the machinery. `join()` also serves another vital purpose: there is, in general, no good way to report exceptions that happen in worker processes, because what they're doing has nothing to do with the main program. `join()` provides a synchronization point, and doing a `join()` is sometimes the **only** way you can see exceptions that were raised in worker processes.

Comment: Thanks so much for your explanation! I just added the pool.join() before the pool.close(). However, the error jumped out saying "Pool is still running". Does that mean it cannot be closed? Should I do something to close it properly?

Comment: Wrong order: `close` first, _then_ `join`.